# UI for taxonomies & query vars

Tags: taxonomy, user-interface

I'm building a review category on our site and I'm wondering what would be the best way to build an UI for sorting the reviews.

This is how it will be setup:

A archive of reviews at /reviews/

The reviews are categorized based for example on the genre and country of origin. I would like the user to be able to first chose for example comedy, which would bring up all the comedy reviews. After that he could chose usa, which would bring up all the comedies made in the usa. All this is standard wordpress features (no extra queries required), but I'm wondering how to build the UI?

Any ideas would be appreciated!